# is there a way to check to see if a reference exists to prevent compile errors?

Tags: vb.net

`microsoft.office.interop.excel` is missing but I need to be able to check for it to prevent this error.

If the reference doesn't exist (it's not installed on my computer), I'd like to conditionally load something else instead.

I tried to show a picture but I haven't had enough posts so I'm not allowed to do so yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. When Excel is not installed on the development machine, you get a compile error which tells you that fact. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but why not just install the dll so you can reference it in your project? This should help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9e83756-4ae2-4ed4-b154-1537f3bb3a22/cant-find-microsoftofficeinteropexceldll?forum=netfxsetup

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. My question was, I'd like to check to see if excel is installed before i try to reference it somehow.  If so i want to use Excel, if its not, id like to do something else conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

This is more about addressing *runtime* errors where an assembly isn't found; you can't publish your code if it won't even compile. You'll need to either add the missing dll or install Excel to compile.

You can add this handler to your project's (static) type initializer:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf EmbeddedAssembly.GetMissingAssembly
```

(I have a class called `EmbeddedAssembly` with a method `GetMissingAssembly()` but you can simply call a sub/function such as `MissingReference()` if you like.)

The function signature looks like most handlers but note the event argument (`e`) type:

```
Public Shared [Sub|Function] GetMissingAssembly(
    ByVal s As Object,
    ByVal e As ResolveEventArgs) [As Assembly]
```

In the handler you can decide what to do, whether it's throw an error or, better, unpack and use an assembly embedded in your project's `Resources`.

There're plenty of references on S.O. about embedding assemblies as `Resources`. Another option is *FodyWeavers* which you can also find info about here. I've moved to the latter from the former mainly because it works and is less work or maintenance.

I should add a warning that when I first started resolving and embedding assemblies, etc, it was a fairly steep learning curve, especially since my project was a commercial app which had to be bullet-proof. My recommendation is create a small test project and get that all working first before you jump in with something more complicated.